# Is the idiom 'speaks volumes about' valid in a formal context?

Tags: idioms, formality

Looking on how to improve my essays, I've just come across the idiom 'speaks volumes about'. For example:

> The unsightly yard and unpainted house speaks volumes about what kind of people live there.

However, all the examples I've seen use it in kind of informal way. Would it be valid to be included in a formal essay?

**PS:** One example of a formal use would be writing to your college director to do some proposal to improve building's installations:

> The anual asset from the magazine has given an outstanding review of the college, which speaks volumes about it. However...

Comment: It depends how formal and for what  purpose the essay is.

Comment: Could you add what you would consider a formal use example?

Comment: I've extended my post a bit providing more info. Thanks

Comment: A **volume** is a book in a series.  We don't tend to use the phrase of written works.  We wouldn't say, for example, that a newspaper or magazine article "speaks volumes" about a particular subject.  The first example you've given shows how it is used -- we use it of things which cannot communicate, like an untidy yard or an unpainted house.

Comment: What do you mean by *asset*? Do you mean [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/asset)? (Oxford dictionary definition).

Comment: @TRomano I just tried to provide a valid example of formality, maybe I got confused in the meaning. But the way I want to use it is as in the first example. Is it valid in a formal way?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "formal". What is the context?

Comment: @TRomano a context could be the one I mentioned in the post script, about writing a proposal for your college director

Comment: I'm not sure what a "college *director*" is.  Your advisor?  A dean of some kind?

Comment: @TRomano yes, your advisor, for example

Comment: In a private communication between yourself and the advisor, such an idiom would be okay (if used properly). No advisor I've ever known would take exception to it in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom *[speak volumes (about something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/speak-volumes)* refers to communication without words, which is why, in your examples,  a yard and a house can be said to speak.

> If something speaks volumes, it makes an opinion, characteristic, or situation very clear without the use of words:
>   *She said very little but her face spoke volumes.*

(Cambridge)

See also the other definitions and examples given at [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/speak+volumes).

Applying the idiom to written communication does not represent natural usage of the idiom.

It does not seem out of place regarding formality in the sentence you wrote. So, yes, the idiom can be used in a formal essay, including "writing to your college director to do some proposal to improve building's installations."